# how to connect two table by the use of primary-foreign key?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to MySQL and facing following problem:

in`info` database `girls` & `girls_info` tables are there. Now, i want to connect this two table by the use of `id` primary key of `girls` and want to make it foreign key in other `girls_info` table. how i do that?

i facing to many error, that i can't understand say, AUTO_INCREMENT, CONSTRAINTS, SYNTAX errors. meaning of above terms i know, but practically i have no idea.

Comment: I suggest you look up all these concepts in a good book or tutorial first, then attempt to design/code.

Comment: You can write a SQL query that joins these two tables and gets the required columns for you. Here's a tutorial with an example: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqljoins.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created the sample tables with example column names you can add/remove columns in the table. 

To use **foreign key constraint** you have to make both the tables as INNO DB, also the column in this case girl_id should have same definition in both the tables

For a better understanding on foreign keys. Read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

**SAMPLE MYSQL DUMP**

```
CREATE TABLE `girls` (
      `girl_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `other_info` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`girl_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


    CREATE TABLE `girls_info` (
      `girl_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
      `age` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`girl_id`),
      CONSTRAINT `girl_id` FOREIGN KEY (`girl_id`) REFERENCES `girls` (`girl_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```